# Reply email powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, automation, reply

Hi again StackOverflow's comunity, I will ask about method ".reply()". This is the code I am trying:

```
function Unread ($correo) {
    if(($correo -eq $null) -or ($correo.Unread.ToString() -like "False")){
        $Noleido = $false
    }else{  
        $Noleido = $true
     return $Noleido
    }
}

    $body = "Bla bla bla"
    $firma = "I am here"
    #$cuerpo = "A test ps"
    $subject = "Re: automated reply"
    $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
    $OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item($buzon1).Folders
    #Map la bandeja de entrada.
    $bandeja_de_entrada=$OutlookFolders.Item("INBOX_FOLDER")

    #Creamos el objeto que hace referencia a la bandeja de entrada y los mensajes que contiene.
    $all_mail=$bandeja_de_entrada.Items


foreach ($mail in $all_mail){ 
    $flag1 = Unread($mail)
    if($flag1 -eq $true){     
       #$mail.to = ""         
       $mail.body =" $cuerpo" +"$firma"
       $mail.subject = $subject
       $mail.reply()
   }
}
```

Dont send the email.

Its solved in a answer

Comment: Be more specific. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Dont work $mail.reply(), the email doesnt send. I am ask about method to reply with the historic email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `reply` creates a MailItem prepopulated with the necessary properties based on the original mail.

If you save the MailItem created by the `reply` method to a variable you can then use the method `send` to actually send the reply.

Modifying your script to look something like the following would probably work.

```
$body = "Bla bla bla"
    $firma = "I am here"
    $subject = "A test ps"
    $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
    $OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item($buzon1).Folders
    #Map la bandeja de entrada.
    $bandeja_de_entrada=$OutlookFolders.Item("INBOX_FOLDER")

    #Creamos el objeto que hace referencia a la bandeja de entrada y los mensajes que contiene.
    $all_mail=$bandeja_de_entrada.Items

    foreach ($mail in $all_mail){      
       #$mail.to = ""
       $reply = $mail.reply()
       $reply.body = " $cuerpo $firma"
       $reply.subject = $subject
       $reply.send()
    }
```

If you want to include the original message instead of overwriting it you could change the `$reply.body`-line to something like this;

```
$reply.body = $reply.body + " $cuerpo $firma"
```

Comment: Nice, the email is sending now, but the historic of conversation email isnt go.

Of course, if you wanna try the script you must put in $buzon1 your email address.

Comment: By historic do you mean what was said in the original email? If that's the case then it's because you overwrite the previous value with `$reply.body = " $cuerpo $firma"`. I've edited my answer to include a way to add to the body instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Very thanks, its working. I edit the original and we can say this is end. Very thanks for the help.

I put the concatenation in other order and dont put subject to use the original subject of email with RE:

Comment: @LCabaAres You should leave your original question the way it was and accept my answer as a solution to your problem. As it is right now you might not help future visitors with the same problem as you had.